# R - Web Scraping attribute containing special character

Tags: r, web-scraping, special-characters

I'm trying to send a request to the following html line:

```
<SELECT scrolling="auto" class="fundo_select_tabnet" NAME="SRegião_Metropolitana_-_RIDE" ID="S8" SIZE=10 MULTIPLE>
```

"R" doesn't allow me to use the tag name and answers with this message:
"Error: unexpected symbol in "SRegião_Metropolitana_-_RIDE"

I believe it interprets the "-" symbol as an attempt to subtract

```
url <-"http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/deftohtm.exe?ibge/cnv/popsvsbr.def"

query <- list(c(Linha = "Município", 
           Coluna = "Faixa_Etária_2", 
           Incremento = "População_residente", 
           Arquivos = "pop21.dbf", 
           SRegião = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes2 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SUnidade_da_Federação = "25", 
           pesqmes3 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SMunicípio = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes4 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SCapital = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes5 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SRegião_de_Saúde = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes6 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SMacrorregião_de_Saúde = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes7 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SMicrorregião_IBGE = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes8 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SRegião_Metropolitana_-_RIDE = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes9 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           STerritório_da_Cidadania = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes10 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SMacrorregião_PNDR = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           SAmazônia_Legal = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           SSemiárido = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           SFaixa_de_Fronteira = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           SZona_de_Fronteira = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           SMunicípio_de_extrema_pobreza = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           SSexo = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes17 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SFaixa_Etária_1 = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           pesqmes18 = "Digite+o+texto+e+ache+fácil", 
           SFaixa_Etária_2 = "TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__", 
           formato = "prn", 
           mostre = "Mostra"))

page<- httr::GET(url = url, query = query) >
  getElement("content") |>
  rawToChar()
```

Is there a way to send the correct information to the server without breaking "R"?

Comment: Can you edit to include the full code for the request?

Comment: Also, the link tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/deftohtm.exe?popsvs/cnv/popbr.def is not working when I click on it

Comment: Hi, The address was recently changed. I've included the new one now.